# django-filter custom descending label

Tags: python, django, label, django-filter

I am new with django-filter and tried to find a way to change auto-generated labels. Inside my filter class I have

```
    ordering = django_filters.OrderingFilter(
        fields=(
            ('price', 'Price'),
       ),

    )
```

which gives me list of options like this:

> *Price
>
> *Price (descending)

Is there any way to custom descending label. For example I would like to have labels like:

> *Price (lower to higher)
>
> *Price (higher to lower)

I know about `field_labels={}` and how to change ascending labels, but how can I use it with descending option?
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the `choices` argument [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html?highlight=ordering#orderingfilter). It seems you can do something like these: `choices=(('price', 'Price (lower to higher)'), ('-price', 'higher to lower'))`

Comment: Oh, I see thanks :)